# Python urllib2 cookies will print but won't save

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I can iterate through the cookies of an HTTPS response but I can't save them to disk. Why not?

```
cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar('mycookies.txt')

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)

handlers = [
    HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPSHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies)
    ]

headers = {
    /* headers go here */
    }

# create and install the opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(*handlers)

def fetch(uri):
    req = urllib2.Request(uri, headers)
    return opener.open(uri)

def dump():
    for cookie in cookies:
        print cookie.name, cookie.value


# retrieve the result
resp = fetch(url)
dump()
cookies.save()
```

When I run the code, the cookies from the response are printed to the console, but when I open up the `mycookies.txt` file, all I see is `#LWP-Cookies-2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The final line needs to look like this:

```
cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar('myaxis.cookies')
```